# How to show the microphone status in the top panel

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, top-bar

I'm running Ubuntu Focal with the standard Yaru gnome theme. The speaker icon is okay with showing the status (muted/low/high/boosted), but the microphone icon doesn't, it just shows the static mic picture. I have looked inside the `/usr/share/icons/../status` folder and it does contain those mic status icons, as well as the speaker ones. But the microphone status is constantly `/usr/share/icons/../devices/audio-input-microphone.svg`. How can I make it show the status icons instead?